# Как при помощи foreign key удалять связанные записи в другой таблице при удалении записи из ссылаемой таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `avatars` и таблица `users`. В таблице `users` есть поле `avatar_id`. Как связать эти таблицы так, чтобы при удалении пользователя, удалялся и аватар, на который ссылается этот пользователь?

Если бы наоборот `avatars` ссылался на пользователя, то в этой ситуации понятно в таблице `avatars` добавляем `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES uasers (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE`. Тогда при удалении пользователя удалится и запись аватарки, которая на него ссылается. Но в моём случае пользователь ссылается на аватарку.

Comment: *в моём случае пользователь ссылается на аватарку.* Это ошибка. Аватара - атрибут пользователя, а не наоборот.

Comment: А если аватарки есть не только у пользователей, но к примеру и у компаний?

Comment: В таком случае какое удаление? одного юзера удалил, его аватару удалил, остальные остались голенькими?

Comment: Не так. Есть таблица аватарок. Она одна для пользователей, фирм и прочих. Когда человек загружает аватарку, она записывается в таблицу аватарок. На одного пользователя одна аватарка. Для фирм так же. Если пользователь удалится и аватарка удалится то никто не пострадает. В любом случае, вопрос был в том, возможно ли сделать так как я хочу или записи можно удалять только при удалении записи из ссылающейся таблицы.

Comment: Т.е. аватара - атрибут пользователя. Т.е. аватара должна ссылаться на пользователя, а не наоборот. О чём я в начале и сказал.

Comment: @Akina тогда надо было бы сделать, чтобы аватарка могла ссылаться в одних случаях на пользователя, в других на фирму, в третьих ещё на кого-то. Опять повторю, вопрос в другом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER on_delete_user BEFORE DELETE ON users FOR EACH ROW
    DELETE FROM avatars WHERE id=OLD.avatar_id;|

DELIMITER ;
```

[Документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)